# Navigating Obj Within Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, console, immutability, immutable.js

Im struggling with Immutable.js:

My state is like this:

```
import { List as list,
         Map as map } from "immutable";

const initialTabState = list.of(
    map({
        tabClass : "tabPreview tab activeTab",
        tabName : "Preview"
    }),
    map({
        tabClass : "tabBody tab",
        tabName : "Body"
    }),
    map({
        tabClass : "tabSleeve tab",
        tabName : "Sleeve"
    })
);
```

In my reducer function, I get `typeError: initialTabState.isList is not a function` when I do this :

```
console.log( "Initial State is...", initialTabState.isList() );
```

And how do I 'read' the value of third Map obj nested within the 'initialTabState' if I was to read it in console, or want to use it within a component?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'd recommend not to change the capitalisation of your imports. `Map` is something different than `map`.

Comment: From how I read the docs, it's `List.isList(initialTabStateList)`, not `initialTabStateList.isList()`.

Comment: @Bergi, you are correct. Thank you for the info. I find the docs at Immutable.js to be most confusing... more confusing then helpful. Or maybe we have been spoilt by the awesome redux docs.